# How to display different columns and remove them using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59dLA.png)

I have csv file like this with 10000 different parameters some of the parameters are empty and some of the parameters have only 0 and 1 combination. I want to display the parameters with 0 and 1 combination and I want to remove the parameters which are empty from the table and then I have to display the table without NA, NaN and empty values.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first drop the columns or parameters which are empty and select the rows with only 1 or 0 values.

To get column names which are having all null values

```
df.columns[df.isna().all()]
```

Next step you can drop null columns.

```
df.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.loc[:, ((df==0) | (df==1)).all()]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but still i am unable to print the columns with empty values

Comment: You want the column names whose are having empty values. I have edited my code please check it.

Comment: how to display the file without empty values. I want to remove the whole column with empty vales and with NA vales

Comment: I would suggest to have a look to my answer maybe faster than this one. Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

```
Putting Together the Dataframe
```

To get started, let’s put together a sample dataframe that you can use throughout the rest of the tutorial. Take a look at the code below to put together the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Nik', 'Jim', 'Alice', 'Jane', 'Matt', 'Kate'],
               'Score': [100, 120, 96, 75, 68, 123],
               'Height': [178, 180, 160, 165, 185, 187],
```

'Weight': [180, 175, 143, 155, 167, 189]})`enter code here`

```
print(df.head())

By using the df.head() function, you can see what the dataframe’s first five rows look like:


Name    Score   Height  Weight
```

0   Nik 100 178 180
1   Jim 120 180 175
2   Alice   96  160 143
3   Jane    75  165 155
4   Matt    68  185 167

```
DataFrame.drop(self, labels=None, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')
```

Comment: Please check the data table

Answer (score 0):

1. Load your csv :

---

For this we will use the very useful library [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_your_file)
```

2. With [pandas.Series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) :

---

It will return a boolean Series showing whether each element in the Series matches an element in the passed sequence of values exactly. After that you drop the not a number (NaN) values. You can use in one line :

```
df[df.isin([0, 1])].dropna(axis=1)
```

I think it will be faster than the first answer and the condition with `.all()`. Maybe a time comparison can be helpful for you, with your dataset.